# createTextLengthConstraint is not working if length is 0?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to display an error message if the cell is empty.

So, I wrote:

```
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) helper.createTextLengthConstraint(OperatorType.GREATER_THAN, "0", "1000"); // 1000 for unlimited
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(3, 12, cellIndex, cellIndex);
XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation) helper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
validation.createErrorBox("Error", "it is empty");
validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

However, if I left the cell empty, no error message is displayed. Is it normal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Excel`'s data validation it is not possible to prohibit empty cells. Set of **Ignore blank** checkbox unchecked only prevents an existing cell to get changed from any value to an empty value. But selecting a cell in Excel and then pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> deletes the whole cell and not only empties the cell value. But the data validation does not work on cells which are not already present. So the error message only occurs if the user deletes the cell content in the edit bar or in cell edit mode and not by pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> for the whole cell. I would call that a insufficiency in `Excel`'s data validation. But this is nothing what apache poi could heal. Data validation runs in `Excel`'s GUI and `apache poi` does not interact with `Excel`'s GUI.

What one could do is using a custom data validation constraint which prevents empty cells above the current cell. For example if column `A` needs to be filled continual, the following formula would check that:

`=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,"")=0`

Starting in `A1` it checks whether there are any empty ( `""`) cells above. If so, then the `COUNTIF` does not result in `0`. Since the row number in `$A1` is not fixated, it is `$A2` in row 2, `$A3` in rown 3 and so on.

So that formula used in  a custom data validation constraint leads to error messages if there are any empty cells above the current cell.

Complete Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;

class CreateExcelDataValidationPreventEmptyCells {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 10, 0, 0);
  DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createCustomConstraint("COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,\"\")=0");

  DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
  validation.setEmptyCellAllowed(false);
  validation.createPromptBox("Prompt", "Please let no cells empty above that cell.");
  validation.createErrorBox("Error", "There are empty cells above that cell. Please fill.");
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) validation.setShowPromptBox(true);
  sheet.addValidationData(validation);

  FileOutputStream out = null;
  if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationPreventEmptyCells.xls");
  } else if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationPreventEmptyCells.xlsx");
  }
  workbook.write(out);
  workbook.close();
  out.close();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code snip.

```
  DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
  validation.setEmptyCellAllowed(false);
```